# Select2 - title not text getting populated on ajax change

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

have the following SELECT2 4.0 code, for some reason it won't populate the text of the newly generated select option DOM html instead it puts it in the title of the option... any help gratefully appreciated!

Initial Select generation (templates excluded)

```
  $("#Clinician, #Admin").select2({
      ajax: {
    url: "jsonOutput.asp",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term,
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo,
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection,
    formatNoMatches: function( term ) {
    alert("No Matches E3 box");
    }
});
```

Model for data entry of new item

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add New ' + recipient)
    modal.find('#updVal_mod').val(recipient)
    modal.find('#selOpts').val($('#'+recipient).val())

})
```

Capture the new data from modal form and re-populate the SELECT2

```
        var frm = $('#addPersForm');

    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

                        alert( $('#updVal_mod').val() );

                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            $("#"+$('#updVal_mod').val()).append('<option value="' + data.items[0].id + '">' + data.items[0].text + '</option>');


                var selectedValues = $("#"+$('#updVal_mod').val()).val();
                if (selectedValues == null) {
                    selectedValues = new Array();
                }
                selectedValues.push(data.items[0].id);

                $("#"+$('#updVal_mod').val()).val(selectedValues).trigger('change');
            }
        });


        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```